# How to communicate with a REST API in Angular?

Tags: angular, mongodb, express

im working on a web angular app where in globalservice.ts i have basepath:string = "https://myapi.com/api/v2/" i have to get data from this api . so i used below mention code in server.js . any suggestions how can i achieve this task please ? and thanks in advance for your reply.

**server.js** 
posted a chunk of code where i have used the baseurl

```
require("./src/routes/index.js")(app);
// set URL, listen for requests
const URL = process.env.URL || "https://myapi.com/api/v2/";
app.listen(URL, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${URL}.`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular is a (web)-client framework and normally would not host a backend service that accesses a database.

The snippet you posted is from Express, a popular web server JavaScript framework, e.g. see the [getting started guide](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html).

When you have your backend server running, you can take a look at this example on how to communicate with it from Angular using the [http client](https://angular.io/guide/http).

```
this.http.get(URL).subscribe(result => doSomething(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using libraries like [express js](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)

Expressjs works with node for creating a server that listens to api call.

No sure if it would work in a angular context

Comment: yes, need to configure/set a port where the process would listen for the incoming requests. ( ex - 8080)